# Load PHP generated HTML with JS in HTML div class doesn`t work anymore

Tags: javascript, php, html

Some time ago I put up a Twitch.tv stream status indicator with a little help of a friend on my website, but suddenly it`s not showing up anymore.

This is my setup:

Folder where all of my files for this are included. An index.php file that provides the HTML Code is working when opening the directory with the browser and is showing the correct status.

In this folder I also have the following JS File, that should load the HTML output:

```
var myRequest = new Request({
    url: 'https://myurl.de/twitch/',
    method: 'get',
    onRequest: function(){
        document.getElementById('streamNavList').set('html', '<img src="/twitch/loader.gif" />');
    },
    onSuccess: function(data){
        document.getElementById('streamNavList').set('html', data);
    }
}).send();
```

My HTML Code to show is:

```
<div id="streamNavList"></div>
```

At the moment nothing is displayed where the status would be.

This has worked in the past. I can`t remember whether I changed anything relevant to this.
When opening the PHP generated HTML directly it works perfectly.
So I assume it has something to do with the JS loading, but can not figure out what...

Would be great if someone could help me out here.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: 1) Check your browser's dev console for errors. 2) Where does `Request` come from? 3) Where does `Element.set()` come from? _Edit: ok, looks like Mootools_

Comment: `console.log(data)` in success and check what you get.

Comment: I have looked into this again. Right as you said "Mootools" it made click and my search began. Seemed that my way of loading Mootools from google is outdated and now got blocked. I need to include a new version of Mootools in my <header> and change the way it`s getting loaded from Google. Thanks for you help guys. How could i be so blind....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mistake was loading Mootools via the outdated Google jsapi.

Loading it directly with:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.6.0/mootools.min.js"></script>
```

fixed the Problem.

Thanks for your help.